# Javascript array to Java array using JSON Adventure

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a situation. I'm creating a normal JavaScript array that contains a number of arrays. Since JavaScript is used completely, `request.setAttribute()` can't be used. So I' doing `JSON.stringify(<array>)` and passing the String as a parameter to a URL. This is how I'm populating my normal JavaScript array-

```
var arrayOfArrays = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<agent.length;i++){    
        var arrayOfStrings = new Array();
        arrayOfStrings[0] = agent[i].comp;
        arrayOfStrings[1] = agent[i].ip;
        arrayOfStrings[2] = agent[i].port;
        arrayOfStrings[3] = agent[i].username;
        arrayOfStrings[4] = agent[i].password;      

            arrayOfArrays[i] = arrayOfStrings;
}
var agents = JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays);
// and I'm passing the agents variable as a parameter to a URL.
```

In the second page, I'm getting the Stringified value using `request.getParameter()` and trying to convert it to a Java `array` using the classes and methods of `net.sf.json` package and continuing with my logic.

The following is the array of arrays I've created which is of the form `[[...],[...],[...], . . ]`-

```
"[[\"hari2\", \"2.2.2.2\", \"222\", \"2gsz3dg\", \"sdfg2sd3\"], [\"fhf\", \"1.4.5.6\", \"678\", \"gjh\", \"gfhjgf\"], [\"hari1\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"sdfg\", \"w34tr5\"], [\"ch\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"ghf\", \"dgjyt\"], [\"hari\", \"1.2.3.4\", \"324\", \"xcfhd\", \"serteg34g\"], [\"hari5\", \"5.5.5.5\", \"555\", \"555\", \"555\"], [\"hari4\", \"4.4.4.4\", \"444\", \"444\", \"444\"], [\"hari3\", \"3.3.3.3\", \"333\", \"sfse\", \"3rw\"], [\"hari6\", \"6.6.6.6\", \"666\", \"666\", \"666\"]]"
```

Here is my logic for converting from String to array-

```
String agents = request.getParameter("agents");

System.out.println("Agents before removing \" :: " + agents);
if (agents.startsWith("\"") && agents.endsWith("\"")) {
    String agentsTemp = agents.replaceFirst("\"", "");
    agents = agentsTemp.substring(0, agentsTemp.length()-1);
    System.out.println("Agents after removing \" :: " + agents);
}
// applied the above logic as i had got "Invalid JSON String" Exception

if(agents != null && agents.length() > 2) {
    net.sf.json.JSONArray arrayOfArrays = (net.sf.json.JSONArray) net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(agents); 

    for(int i=0; i<arrayOfArrays.size();i++) {
        net.sf.json.JSONArray arrayOfStrings = (net.sf.json.JSONArray) arrayOfArrays.get(i);

        String pgData = arrayOfStrings.getString(0);
        String user = arrayOfStrings.getString(3);
        String pwd = arrayOfStrings.getString(4);
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfStrings.getString(2));
        String hostIP = arrayOfStrings.getString(1);

                    // business logic continued
    }
} else {
    // throw exception
}


net.sf.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 2 of [[\"hari2\", \"2.2.2.2\", \"222\", \"2gsz3dg\", \"sdfg2sd3\"], [\"fhf\", \"1.4.5.6\", \"678\", \"gjh\", \"gfhjgf\"], [\"hari1\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"sdfg\", \"w34tr5\"], [\"ch\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"ghf\", \"dgjyt\"], [\"hari\", \"1.2.3.4\", \"324\", \"xcfhd\", \"serteg34g\"], [\"hari5\", \"5.5.5.5\", \"555\", \"555\", \"555\"], [\"hari4\", \"4.4.4.4\", \"444\", \"444\", \"444\"], [\"hari3\", \"3.3.3.3\", \"333\", \"sfse\", \"3rw\"], [\"hari6\", \"6.6.6.6\", \"666\", \"666\", \"666\"]]
```

What is it expecting there? If there is any easier way to solve this issue, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: JSON should always be one object with properties. Try to wrap your `arrayOfArrays` in an object: `var out = {}; out.myArray = arrayOfArrays`. Then `stringify()` that object and pass it. Also, by accessing `arrayOfStrings` via indices, it should be intialized with a proper size: `var arrayOfStrings = new Array(5);`

Comment: @MCL: That is incorrect. Using `JSON.stringify([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])` and then outputting that to `JSON.parse` works just fine. JSON doesn't have to be "One Object", it can be an array.

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't say it had to be, I said it **should** be by convention.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back that up? The same for your claim one "Should" initialize arrays with a proper size? (Functionally, accessing `myArray[3]` on a `new Array()` or a `new Array(5)`, or a `new Array(2)` makes absolutely no difference.)

Comment: @Cerbrus I actually don't have any documentation. Counterquestion: Do you know any popular JSON API that doesn't output exactly **one** object? Please put me right, if there isn't some kind of convention implied. Also, what would ajax callback functions do if there were every kind of arbitrary values possible to be dealt with? The array thing might work functionally, but if you know the array size at the beginning, what's the harm in telling the interpreter that? I believe this could also result in less memory usage, since the array doesn't need to expanded when items are added.

Comment: @user1649068 Please read my comment above and try to wrap your array in an object. When pasting your JSON in a [JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), it shows a really weird output.

Comment: @MCL: You're telling me it _"should"_ be an object, not an array, without telling me why it should. I'm just saying that the root element doesn't _"have"_ to be an object, it can just as well be an array, int, boolean, whatever.

Now, for the array thing, it appears [Chrome / Firefox are optimised for arrays with a preset length](http://jsperf.com/array-initialisation-with-without-length), for the other browsers, there is barely any difference. Interesting...

Comment: @Cerbrus Knowing, that there will be generally an object in a JSON string makes traversing easier, especially, if you don't know the exact structure and maybe want to loop over the properties first. The fact that most (if not, all) public JSON APIs do exactly that supports my point. I didn't say that in this case, there will be a difference, but generelly, I would recommend always wrapping JSON in one object. The better effiency of a fixed array (perceptible or not) is simply intuitive.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't scientifically correctly prove each of my statements with sources, I'm rather appealing to intuition and a good sense of clean programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse()`.

This code:

```
JSON.parse("[[\"hari2\", \"2.2.2.2\", \"222\", \"2gsz3dg\", \"sdfg2sd3\"], [\"fhf\", \"1.4.5.6\", \"678\", \"gjh\", \"gfhjgf\"], [\"hari1\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"sdfg\", \"w34tr5\"], [\"ch\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"123\", \"ghf\", \"dgjyt\"], [\"hari\", \"1.2.3.4\", \"324\", \"xcfhd\", \"serteg34g\"], [\"hari5\", \"5.5.5.5\", \"555\", \"555\", \"555\"], [\"hari4\", \"4.4.4.4\", \"444\", \"444\", \"444\"], [\"hari3\", \"3.3.3.3\", \"333\", \"sfse\", \"3rw\"], [\"hari6\", \"6.6.6.6\", \"666\", \"666\", \"666\"]]");
```

Outputs the correct array of arrays.:

```
[
    ["hari2", "2.2.2.2", "222", "2gsz3dg", "sdfg2sd3"],
    ["fhf",   "1.4.5.6", "678", "gjh",     "gfhjgf"],
    ["hari1", "1.1.1.1", "123", "sdfg",    "w34tr5"],
    ["ch",    "1.1.1.1", "123", "ghf",     "dgjyt"],
    ["hari",  "1.2.3.4", "324", "xcfhd",   "serteg34g"],
    ["hari5", "5.5.5.5", "555", "555",     "555"],
    ["hari4", "4.4.4.4", "444", "444",     "444"],
    ["hari3", "3.3.3.3", "333", "sfse",    "3rw"],
    ["hari6", "6.6.6.6", "666", "666",     "666"]
]
```

Comment: Is that Java code? I believe OP wants to parse the array with his Servlet/JSP.

Comment: @MCL, oh, I overlooked the java tag.